# Translating a point

Tags: geometry

This is is my first time posting here. I'm not at all fluent in mathematics and math terms, so I'll try to explain my problem in the best way I can.
I'm trying to make a software that would plot a 3D graph. Each point in the plot has x,y and z values. 
I'm using an external library to plot the graph and in this library I have to assign the plot axis manually. If I have the following point values in x,y,z order;

```
(1, 1.5, 8.9)
(1, 1.6, 8.8)
(1, 1.7, 8.6)
(2, 1.8, 8.4)
(2, 1.9, 7.3)
(2, 2.0, 6.1)
(3, 2.1, 5.0)
(3, 2.2, 4.8)
```

What I would do is plot the points according to the values and add the graph axis bounds as following (minimum axis value, maximum axis value);

```
X axis - (1,3)
Y axis - (1.5,2.2)
Z axis - (4.8,8.9)
```

This would give me a graph with a rather long z axis. Now I was given a requirement that the graph should be of cubic shape, that is all the axis should be of the same length but the distance between 2 points of the axis should be scaled accordingly.

If I apply the length of Z axis to the other 2 axis, I would have to increase the distance between two points of those axis. How can I calculate the distance?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. (I'm not sure what to tag this, so I'm just tagging it homework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a stupid answer; if this is the case, please forgive me.

You have your data X, Y and Z. Will it help if you define a new set of coordinates such that

x = (X - X_min) / (X_max - X_min)
y = (Y - Y_min) / (Y_max - Y_min)
z = (Z - Z_min) / (Z_max - Z_min)

In such a case, all values will be between 0 and 1 and you get the cube.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the effort. It did not render a cube shape, but the results were better than before.

Comment: @Madz. What I was meaning is that, using these axis, he function is represented in a cube of 1 since all your values are between 0 and 1.